# How do I authenticate against my ASPNET users and roles stored in my database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I have an MVC project allows my users to add users and Roles to the `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUsers` tables. The application uses Active Directory to authenticate users on the Login View. In my database I have added user `user123` to the role of `Administrators` in my database. I have added the following logic to make this link visible to the `Administrators` role in my login partial.

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Manage Accounts", "Index", "Roles")
}
```

I also added this to my web.config in an attempt to instantiate the  role provider connection to the database.

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
         name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
         applicationName="MyApplicationName" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

However, my link is still invisible to `user123` who according to my database is a member of `Administrators`. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simultaneously mixing Identity, ASP.NET Membership, and Windows Auth, all of which are inherently incompatible with each other. If you're using Identity, role providers and such are out the window. That's all part of ASP.NET Membership, which is replaced by Identity. Windows Auth is an entirely different beast as well and doesn't work with individual authentication provided by Identity or ASP.NET Membership.

If you want to employ your own authentication system *and* you want to authenticate via AD, then you cannot use Windows Auth. Instead, you must manually connect to your AD via LDAP and run your authorization against that. You will still need the actual user records in your system, provided by Identity (since no one should be using ASP.NET Membership anymore), but you wouldn't use Identity to actually verify the user/password combo. Instead, you would do that via LDAP, and then simply sign the user in on the Identity side.

Comment: Chris, I am authenticating through LDAP. I am logging into my application via AD credentials, and it can see if the username and password is valid. MY login partial is using Identity. I think my role provider is set up wrong. However this is the first time I have attempted something like this and I am fairly new to MVC.

Comment: I can guarantee your role provider is set up wrong because Identity doesn't use role providers.

Comment: ok...When I remove the string from the webconfig, how do I get the app to authenticate using the roles in the database?

Comment: Originally I did not have the role provider in the web.config but my login partial does not see that my logged in user is in the Administrators group